# How do I write test class for Platform Event triggers in Salesforce?

Tags: trigger, platform-event

I have created a simple Trigger on Platform Event, i created a test class & i observed it is not covering Trigger.

Comment: Can you please add your code, so far what have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

The only real requirement for testing Platform events is given in the Docs for [Test Your Platform Event in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_apex_tests.htm):

> Use `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` to test your platform event in Apex.
>
> Create test event objects, and publish them after the `Test.startTest()` statement. Then call the `Test.stopTest()` statement to publish the test events. Include your validations after the `Test.stopTest()` statement.

So the fairly standard pattern.

1. Call `Test.startTest()`
2. Publish the event
3. Call `Test.stopTest()`
4. Assert the expected outcome of your trigger.